# OnRowUpdating Gridview Input String was not in correct format

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I cannot figure this out for the life of me... I have a gridview with a sqldatasource attached and I format the fee_amt in the editItemtemplate <%# Bind("fee_amt","{0:n}") %> like so. When the OnRowUpdating Event is raised via clicking the update lnk button I get this error. Please also note I format the number in the textbox with a "$" like "$200.00".

I am pretty sure the problem is coming from the fee_amt but I may be wrong.

```
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request.            Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Stack Trace: 


[FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.]
System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number,    NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal) +9592843
System.Number.ParseDecimal(String value, NumberStyles options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt)  +146
System.Convert.ToDecimal(String value, IFormatProvider provider) +67
System.String.System.IConvertible.ToDecimal(IFormatProvider provider) +10
System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, TypeCode typeCode, IFormatProvider provider) +491
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Parameter.GetValue(Object value, String defaultValue, TypeCode type, Boolean convertEmptyStringToNull, Boolean ignoreNullableTypeChanges) +126
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Parameter.GetValue(Object value, Boolean ignoreNullableTypeChanges) +63
System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.AddParameters(DbCommand command, ParameterCollection reference, IDictionary parameters, IDictionary exclusionList, String oldValuesParameterFormatString) +550
System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteUpdate(IDictionary keys, IDictionary values, IDictionary oldValues) +346
System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Update(IDictionary keys, IDictionary values, IDictionary oldValues, DataSourceViewOperationCallback callback) +95
System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.HandleUpdate(GridViewRow row, Int32 rowIndex, Boolean causesValidation) +1226
System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.HandleEvent(EventArgs e, Boolean causesValidation, String validationGroup) +855
System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e) +95
System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args) +37
System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e) +121
System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args) +37
System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.OnCommand(CommandEventArgs e) +125
System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +169
System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +9
System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +176
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +5563




 Protected Sub OnRowUpdating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewUpdateEventArgs)      Handles GridViewDegfaultCharges.RowUpdating

    'OnRowUpdating Sets Update Params for the GridView

    Dim TextBox2 As TextBox    'category
    Dim TextBox3 As TextBox    'fee_name
    Dim TextBox4 As TextBox    'fee_amt
    Dim CheckBox1 As CheckBox  'inactive
    Dim blnValid As Boolean
    lblMessage.Text = ""
    blnValid = True

    TextBox2 = GridViewDegfaultCharges.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("TextBox2")
    TextBox3 = GridViewDegfaultCharges.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("TextBox3")
    TextBox4 = GridViewDegfaultCharges.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("TextBox4")
    CheckBox1 = GridViewDegfaultCharges.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("CheckBox1")



    If CheckDefaultChargesCategory(TextBox2.Text) Then
        lblMessage.Text = TextBox2.Text & " is not a valid Loan Type"
        blnValid = False
        e.Cancel = True
        Exit Sub
    End If



    SqlDataDefaultCharges.UpdateParameters("category").DefaultValue = TextBox2.Text
    SqlDataDefaultCharges.UpdateParameters("fee_name").DefaultValue = TextBox3.Text
    SqlDataDefaultCharges.UpdateParameters("fee_amt").DefaultValue = Convert.ToDecimal(TextBox4.Text).ToString()
    SqlDataDefaultCharges.UpdateParameters("investorID").DefaultValue = Convert.ToInt32(_pageID)
    SqlDataDefaultCharges.UpdateParameters("inactive").DefaultValue = CheckBox1.Checked

    If blnValid Then
        SqlDataDefaultCharges.Update()
    End If




End Sub
```

Comment: Try to remove the $ sign

Comment: Still doesn't seem to want to work... the Parameter field value type on the actual aspx file is a decimal. Not sure if that helps.

Comment: It means somehow 200 was not the value being saved. It is either '$200' or empty string (null) which is not convertible to number

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, I'm not sure how you're handling this value, however, "fee_amt" is being converted to a decimal and then back to a string?

**Before:**

`SqlDataDefaultCharges.UpdateParameters("fee_amt").DefaultValue = Convert.ToDecimal(TextBox4.Text).ToString()`

**After:**

`SqlDataDefaultCharges.UpdateParameters("fee_amt").DefaultValue = Convert.ToDecimal(TextBox4.Text)`

**EDIT:**

Unless of-course this value is supposed to be a `string` in which case using `TextBox4.Text` should suffice.

Based **codingbiz's** comment, if the dollar sign is being added in the `textbox`. A `Convert.ToDecimal()` won't work as '$' is not a numeric value. I assumed you were displaying the '$' next to the `TextBox`.

Comment: I have tried Convert.ToDecimal(TextBox4.Text) alone before I was just adding on the ".ToString()" to see if anything else would happen but I get the same error.